Is there a way to force the instantiation of a member function for every template instanciation?
Given the following code, I would like to have the AST for foo<int>::bar:
// foo.cpp
template <typename T>
struct foo {
    const char *bar() { /* Implementation depending on T. */ }
};

int main() {
    foo<int> f;
}


Is there a way to force the instantiation of the member function bar ? Indeed it is absent from the output of clang++ -Xclang -ast-dump foo.cpp.
I could add template const char* foo<int>::bar(); at namespace scope, but I would have to do it once for every template instance, and I don't want to do that.

you could for example call it. Why do you want it to be instantiated when it is never used?

bar could be moved to a non-template base class as it not depends on the template argument

It will be used, but the call will be made after the compilation phase (the code is not executed, it is given to a special interpreter)

The bar implementation do depend on the template argument, I omitted the actual implementation. I'll update the description to reflect that.

Could you clarify the usage part ? For example, how exactly is the code meant to be used (by your special interpreter) ? Do you generate a shared object ? (assuming you have more than just a class template) Etc... It may be an XY problem

The code will be put into a special debugger. This debugger can print some program values. The user can customize this printing by implementing the bar function. But I would like to give a default implementation for STL containers such as vector. Today, the implementation is lost since nobody call vector::bar in the actual code.

I don't get it... What do you provide to your "interpreter" exactly ? source code ? compiled object ? If so, what do contain that object because you cannot generate anything from a template alone (e.g. a header-only library (with only templates) cannot output a shared object, you need an actual source instantiating the template to be able to generate something), etc... We need more details IMHO

Since your code doesn't call or refer to any instantiation of bar(), an implementation is free to not instantiate it (although it instantiates foo<int>, there is no call/reference to foo<int>::bar()).    Modify your code so it explicitly calls or refers to an instantiation of bar()  - for example, a call of f.bar() in main() [which forces instantiation of foo<int>::bar()] or calculate &foo<int>::bar (may not guarantee instantiation of foo<int>::bar(), but increases the odds of that compiler will instantiate it).

Fortunately, I'm the implementation :)

Making the method virtual would force instiation of that method with the class Demo
To avoid drawback of virtual, you might dummy Odr-use it in constructor:
struct foo {
    foo() { static_cast<void>(&foo::bar); }
    const char *bar() { /* Implementation depending on T. */ }
};

So each implementation of the constructor would implicitly instantiate the given method.
Demo

Well the question is probably an XY problem (since I don't see why would we want to instantiate something we don't use), but this solves the question as written :)

@Fareanor: Might be useful for custom clang tooling analyzing for example.

Oh I see. But are compiler optimizations allowed to optimize it out since the result of the cast is not used ?

@Jarod42 I added decltype(&foo::bar) a = &foo::bar; as a class member (this way I don't mess with constructors). But the idea is still the same.
@Fareanor the code is not compiled, it is only to libclang.
